# Pulling data from API into react-bootstrap-table-2

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I'm pulling in data from an API and trying to display it on my bootstrap table. It displays but I'm getting some errors. The first issue is in regard to 'data' being required. 
[image: Error message]

The second issue seems to be the data hasn't loaded in time but I've used an if statement to load the data first.

```
    if (this.props.dataState.loaded){
         data = this.props.data.content;
        } else {
          this.renderLoading();
        }
    return( ...
```

[image: Issue 2 - cannot read property length of undefined]

Sometimes it displays the page without issues, other times it effects the other components and they won't load. I always get the console errors. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the existence of `dataState` too, the same way you are checking for `dataState.loaded`. For the below code, I am assuming the default Props type for data.content is an array.

Try this:

```
if (this.props.dataState && this.props.dataState.loaded){
         data = this.props.data.content ? this.props.data.content : [] ;
} else {
          this.renderLoading();
       }
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your input Vikas but I'm still getting the same error
" error      TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
even though the data is pulled into the table.

Comment: Could you please write the complete code so that I can have a look at it?